# Yii2 advanced application doesn't work on production server

Tags: server, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I installed Yii2 advanced application on my local server and it works fine, without configured `.htaccess`. But on the server it doesn't work, even with `/frontend/web/index.php` url.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the php version of your hosted server, It Require PHP 5.5 version.

Thank you...

Comment: Yii 2 requires PHP 5.4, not 5.5.

Comment: ofcourse, if you get this kind of error in live server then change the version into 5.5, then you never get this error in yii2

Comment: Did you read my comment actually? It's even mentioned in the beginning of main repository README [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2).